# XPath 2.0 Iteration acting weird

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Iterating at `//Events/Properties` returns all properties but `//Events/Properties[for $me in (.) return $me]` returns nothing. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you are right, then I think it points to a bug in your XPath engine.

The expression `for $me in (.) return $me` is equivalent to `.`, and if expression X selects one or more nodes then `X[.]` should select the same nodes.

Comment: The `for $me in (.) return $me` was a trick from one of my comments on the OP's previous question to determine whether their (unspecified) XPath engine really was 2.0-capable or if it was in fact just 1.0.

Comment: I guess when they say it "returns nothing" it could mean it throws an error and they are ignoring the error...